# Need help with insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Saw this bug in my hallway tonight, crawling alongside the baseboard, it didn't seem like it could crawl up the wall despite trying to countless times. Google wasn't much help, although I saw a weevil that looks sort of similar to it.

Location: Augusta, Georgia, US

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question and add the location where you took this photo. City/state and country is usually sufficient.

Comment: @Chris It's updated now.

Comment: I don't know about weevil, those usually have a long snout looking thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil#Gallery Almost looks like a type of ground beetle, but that's because ground beetles are typically black and boring looking. Plus, it's shaped a lot like this north carolina ground beetle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachinus#/media/File:Brachinus_spPCCA20060328-2821B.jpg

Comment: That is definitely a ground beetle. Family Carabidae. These are running predators. They are rarely found in homes, and are not pests. It must have gotten in by accident.

Comment: @Karl Kjer agreed, and I believe that the out-of-focus photo will not let anyone go deeper than you have (had the palps--the short antenna-like appendages at the front of the head--been in focus we might have eliminated tribe Bembidiini [where the last segment is abruptly narrowed and shortened], but that isn't possible with the evidence at hand).